# How to escape commas inside CSV values when importing table to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV file into a MySQL database table. The CSV rows look like the following:

```
"00602"," ","42042","15590","0","0","0","35","9","67","1978","20608","21434","3.1","54700","11384","31.3","30.4","32","18.382809","-67.186759","0","PR","Puerto Rico","U","","787","AGUADA","URB SAN CRISTOBAL","AGUADA","003","72","4","N","0060","","","10380","","Metro","Aguadilla-Isabela-San Sebastián PR","Aguadilla PR MSA","","","","N","0","0","0","0","","0","0","0","0","0","322569","0","","","5456","415","9577","V17136"," "," ","",""
"00602"," ","42042","15590","0","0","0","35","9","67","1978","20608","21434","3.1","54700","11384","31.3","30.4","32","18.382809","-67.186759","0","PR","Puerto Rico","U","","787","AGUADA","COMUNIDAD LAS FLORES","AGUADA","003","72","4","N","0060","","","10380","","Metro","Aguadilla-Isabela-San Sebastián PR","Aguadilla PR MSA","","","","N","0","0","0","0","","0","0","0","0","0","322569","0","","","5456","415","9577","V17136"," "," ","",""

etc...
```

As you can see, the fields are enclosed in double quotes and separated by commas. However some rows have commas inside the values like so (notice the last value):

```
"00501"," ","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","40.81518","-73.0455","25","NY","New York","N","","631","HOLTSVILLE","I R S SERVICE CENTER","SUFFOLK","103","36","5","Y","5602","5380","408","35620","35004","Metro","New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island NY-NJ-PA","New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island","Nassau-Suffolk, NY PMSA","Northeast","Middle Atlantic","N","7","0","0","0","B","0","0","0","0","0","18640775","2807500","","","0","1","1","V13916","U"," ","New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA","Nassau-Suffolk, NY"
```

This is how my import statement looks like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/file.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE zipcodes 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But it's not working as expected. For example, the first inserted row has a column with the following value:

```
Nassau-Suffolk, NY""00501
```

instead it should have been:

```
Nassau-Suffolk, NY
```

and `00501` should have been inserted as the first column value on the next row.

How to adjust my SQL to work right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), use the following options instead:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Update to match your usage, but the important part is to drop the `OPTIONALLY` from `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`.

Comment: How do we achieve this in a stored procedure, since `LOAD DATA` is not allowed in SPs?

Comment: Adding the \r in the  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' section made it work for me! Thanks!