# Two different view with same exported data (LocalHost and WebServer)

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have created a csv export script with a left join select query. It is working fine at Localhost server(windows 8) with same data, that is not working well when it is at web server(Linux).

Every rows are exporting consecutively at Localhost. But, same query with same MySQL data exporting wrong from web server.

For Example, At row 261 after description column, it is broken to new row with remaining columns of row 261. And from row 263 the data exporting fine till row 415. Again broken after description as a new Excel row. Then again exporting fine till 1133. Again broken after description as a new Excel row.

I can't understand this issue. What is wrong with the script?

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT 
            t1.inqty, IFNULL(t2.outqty, '0') outqty, (IFNULL(t1.inqty,'0') - IFNULL(t2.outqty, '0')) totalHand, 
            t1.serialno, 
            (SELECT projectname FROM projects WHERE t1.project_id = projects.project_id) AS ProjectName, 
            TRIM(t1.productid), 
            TRIM(t1.description), 
            TRIM(t1.revisionstate),
            TRIM(t1.remarks), 
            (SELECT username FROM wms_users WHERE t1.userid = wms_users.id) AS UserName,
            (SELECT cusname FROM customerinfo WHERE t1.cus_id = customerinfo.cus_id) AS CustomerName,
            t1.inserteddate
        FROM
            (
                SELECT *, SUM(in_quantity) inqty FROM stockin GROUP BY serialno
            ) t1 LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT serialno, SUM(out_quantity) outqty FROM stockout GROUP BY serialno
            ) t2
        ON t1.serialno = t2.serialno
        ");
$headings = array('INQTY','OUTQTY','TOTAL IN HAND','SerialNo','Project Name','ProductID','Description','Revision State','Remarks','Username','Customer Name','Inserted Date');
$i = 0;
foreach ($headings as $heading) {
    $csv_output .= $heading . ",";
    $i++;
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
        $csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ",";
    }
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
ob_end_clean();

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
//header("Content-type: text/csv");
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($csv_output) );
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you exported data from localhost using CSV and the data contained comma "," values and you did not enclose your values with a ", this can always happen with CSV method.

You can use LOAD DATA to avoid such issues. An example would be

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

(Above lines taken from [How to escape commas inside CSV values when importing table to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469502/how-to-escape-commas-inside-csv-values-when-importing-table-to-mysql)) for example purposes

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html provides more details

Comment: Infile used for import dear. Outfile used for export

Comment: Hi Sam, yes, that example was for import to avoid lines being identified wrongly

Comment: How can i add fields enclosed by with my script?

Comment: I did not understand the question completely, can you explain

Comment: Look at the while loop of my script. I already used fields terminating at this line `$csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ","`. I asked how may i use fields enclosed by with this line.

Comment: `$csv_output .= '"'.$rowr[$j] . ',"';` would do the trick if you are just looking to add double quotes around the data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36147/discussion-between-skv-and-sam)